# Error retrieving multiple ids using the Stack Exchange API

Tags: swift, stackexchange-api

Working with the Stack Exchange 2.2 API, I have run into a roadblock when using `post_ids` to retrieve data. My results are incomplete.

According [the online documents for the `posts/{ids}` interface](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/posts-by-ids#page=1&pagesize=1&order=desc&sort=activity&ids=3743%3B327738%3B339426&filter=default&site=stackoverflow),
I should be able to retrieve 30 questions. (It says up to 100, but other queries are maxing out at 30, so I assume this would as well.)

But, using this query ("Query 1"):

[/2.2/posts/44697152;44725527;44740511;44740358;44746963;44744722;44752663;44751224;44750591;44768116;44768073;44766268;44762034;44763620;44763575;44763124;44778755;44782321;44792568;44791709;44791955;44801095;44800945;44808174;44809993;44801579;44838390;44872388;44853254;44850293](https://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/posts/44697152;44725527;44740511;44740358;44746963;44744722;44752663;44751224;44750591;44768116;44768073;44766268;44762034;44763620;44763575;44763124;44778755;44782321;44792568;44791709;44791955;44801095;44800945;44808174;44809993;44801579;44838390;44872388;44853254;44850293?site=stackoverflow&order=desc&sort=activity)

I get back exactly 3 entries, those for: 44850293; 44872388; and 44853254.

> (lldb) po result
>
> ["items": [
>
> ["creation_date": 2017-06-30 15:41:31
>   +0000, "link": [How to unwrap the content value from XML in Objective-C](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44850293), "score": -1, "post_type": Wednesday.PostType.question, "last_activity_date":
>   2017-07-03 13:57:21 +0000, "owner": ["link":
>   https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/e0616f34ea00d07842b7e7886fd7abc8?s=128&d=identicon&r=PG&f=1,
>   "user_type": Wednesday.User.UserType.registered, "user_id": 7707593,
>   "display_name": "Steven", "reputation": 18, "accept_rate": 75],
>   "last_edit_date": 2017-07-03 07:41:31 +0000],
>
> ["creation_date":
>   2017-07-02 15:25:37 +0000, "link":
>   [How to collect the return value of a function (Swift 3)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44872388), "score": -4, "post_type":
>   Wednesday.PostType.question, "last_activity_date": 2017-07-02 15:43:58
>   +0000, "owner": ["link": https://lh6.googleusercontent.com/-NIYQgyduM8w/AAAAAAAAAAI/AAAAAAAAAaQ/e0IACRo6xbI/photo.jpg?sz=128,
>   "user_type": Wednesday.User.UserType.registered, "user_id": 6298390,
>   "display_name": "Dorian Brown", "reputation": 18, "accept_rate": 100],
>   "last_edit_date": 2017-07-02 15:43:58 +0000],
>
> ["creation_date":
>   2017-06-30 19:02:07 +0000, "link":
>   [swift - approach for tangled/cross-cutting code (logging, analytics, etc.)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44853254), "score": 0, "post_type":
>   Wednesday.PostType.question, "last_activity_date": 2017-07-01 01:26:24
>   +0000, "owner": ["link": https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/e819b2408e9528b895dc192aee309912?s=128&d=identicon&r=PG&f=1,
>   "user_type": Wednesday.User.UserType.registered, "user_id": 108546,
>   "display_name": "ravun", "reputation": 743, "accept_rate": 86],
>   "last_edit_date": 2017-07-01 01:26:24 +0000]
>
> ],
>
> "quota_remaining": 221,
>
> "quota_max": 300, "has_more": false]

Notice **"has_more": false**  -- so the API thinks it has provided all the information.

Using this query  ("Query 2"):

[/2.2/posts/44218623;44217105;44262473;44272520;44309003;44305981;44319988;44318730;44330107;44329638;44334480;44350820;44354106;44358187;44374565;44374073;44365138;44377970;44388874;44395390;44397545;44401141;44399160;44408394;44454372;44446876;44458876;44461402;44468764;44650412](https://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/posts/44218623;44217105;44262473;44272520;44309003;44305981;44319988;44318730;44330107;44329638;44334480;44350820;44354106;44358187;44374565;44374073;44365138;44377970;44388874;44395390;44397545;44401141;44399160;44408394;44454372;44446876;44458876;44461402;44468764;44650412?site=stackoverflow&order=desc&sort=activity)

I get back 0 entries. **These are all valid ids**

> (lldb) po result
>
> ["quota_max": 300, 
>   "quota_remaining": 224,
>   "has_more": false]

Here is a sample of some the Swift 3.2 code used to call (I don't believe the swift code is the issue):

```
let response: String = try get(url)
guard let json = try parseJSON(response) as? [String:Any] else {
    throw APIError.notDictionary(response: response)
}

open func get(_ url: String) throws -> (Data, HTTPURLResponse) {
    guard let nsUrl = URL(string: url) else {
        throw RequestError.invalidURL(url: url)
    }
    var request = URLRequest(url: nsUrl)
    request.setValue(String(request.httpBody?.count ?? 0), forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Length")
    return try performRequest(request)
}
```

**How do I retrieve a list of 30 posts using the 2.2 API?**
Is there a newer API?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most important thing is that **the API does not return deleted posts**.  There is [a feature request for this](https://stackapps.com/questions/1917/provide-a-way-to-retrieve-questions-and-answers-that-have-been-deleted), you might want to go upvote it.

*However*, [deleted posts return in the API is buggy](https://stackapps.com/questions/6955/why-is-questions-api-returning-deleted-questions), so you might *temporarily* see some deleted posts, as well as [deleted posts that you're not supposed to be able to](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/271062/10k-users-can-still-search-any-users-deleted-content).

Also note, that as a user with less than 10K, theoretically you should never be able to see deleted posts unless you were the author.

In [your doc link](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/posts-by-ids#page=1&pagesize=1&order=desc&sort=activity&ids=3743%3B327738%3B339426&filter=default&site=stackoverflow), you have 3 ids (3743, 327738, and 339426):

- however it only returns 339426.
- [Post 3743 <sup>10K link</sup>](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3743) is deleted.
- But [Post 327738 is valid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/327654/hashtable-to-dictionary-syncroot/327738#327738)!

**This may be a serious bug.**

---

In your "Query 1", all but the last 3 posts are deleted, so **the API is returning the correct entries.**

In your "Query 2", all 30 posts are deleted, so **the API is correct to return nothing.**

---

Re: "Is there a newer API?"

No.  Not officially.
Unofficially, work seems to have started on version 3.0, but it is nowhere near ready for use.

Comment: Let me start with a "Thank you" and an up vote.  I've been running with the assumption that post_ids were permanent, and have been saving those of interest in a Realm db for later research (things I can answer, things you might "favorite", etc.) Should I have been using question_id ??  If the 8K ids I've manually saved are deleted, is there a way to link to what I'm interested in: the original question (normally the post_id and title can get me a url - if the url isn't deleted.) Should I create a new question asking how to store pointers to interesting posts?

Comment: `post_id`s *are* permanent.  It's just that we lesser mortals can't always see them. ;) ... `question_id` and `post_id` are the same if the post is a question. Using `post_id` is fine (bugs excluded).  ... You can link any post, even answers, with a URL like `https://stackoverflow.com/q/327738`. If the post id after the `/q/` is an answer, it will still work but redirect to a URL like `https://stackoverflow.com/questions/327654/hashtable-to-dictionary-syncroot/327738#327738`.  However, if the post is deleted, you will not be able to see it until you get 10K. But `SEDE` has deleted posts.

Comment: Thanks again! I'm writing up a new question on "what needs to be saved" to return to a post later.

Comment: Just post id needs to be saved.  *Nothing* gets you around the 10K barrier for deleted posts though (except SEDE IIRC).

Comment: Oh. by delete I thought you were saying replaced by new versions (edits with a new post_id, etc). You mean, really really deleted. I'm not interested in deleted posts -- I'm amazed that 90% of the questions (from the past month or so) I was interested in were deleted. I guess in the future I'll try to get back to answer them more quickly.

Comment: Yeah, edits do not change the `post_id`.  Revisions have their own id, EG https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/44952606/2, that we only occasionally have use for.